# Dragging condition draw - Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm currently developing a webapp that allows the end-user to draw different shapes. I've set the draw-object up with a condition to check for various things. This includes checking for intersections with other geometry objects.

The issue i have is that the condition is always called, and only returns the "pointerdown"-event. Basically if the user clicks and hold down the mouse (dragging), this leads to the segment not being added drawing due to the "clickTolerance":

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Draw-Draw.html

This is fine, and i don't want to change this. The user should be able to drag the map while drawing. But the problem is that the condition is always called, even though the segment is not added to the drawing.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

I think these examples covers your use case:

Free hand drawing:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-freehand.html

Drawing shapes:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the issue is not the draw function itself, but the event that is passed to the condition property of the Draw object that is created from OL. As it only sends the mousedown event, its not possible to know if the condition should be handled or not if the user is dragging the map, except moving some code out of the property function.

Comment: @Koronag sorry I could not have been of help. I am definitely not an expert on openlayers. Could you talk a little more about your use case? Addressing the issue of not knowing whether the user is dragging the map or not, the way the demo handles it by allowing users to select different 'tools' via a select element. If 'none' is selected, you can drag the map. Maybe an approach like this could work since there seems to be a limitation with the library events is giving you and what you expect to have access to?

Comment: Thanks for the input man. I could not resolve it, but i found the next best thing. I was thinking inside the box (literally inside the scope of the condition property function lol), i moved some of the code outside and individually setup a listener for the pointerup. Did the calculation of distance in pixels, and then went on to do what i needed to do if it was a condition that should be handled. It's not 100%, but it works, and i can visually represent what i need. Thanks again.